looking for a better regex which can do internal recursion
I'm translating code from an old language (FOCAL) which uses " (  )" both for function arguments and for vector indices.   The target language (R) also uses " ( )" for functions but uses "  [  ]"  for indexing.
FOCAL variable names are limited to two characters, and at least to start, I'm assuming all function names have 3 or more (true for all internal functions).   For example, the string
" ab(c(kk)) ab(c(5)) sin(x) qr(g) exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr(3))) cos(y(3))  sin(3)"

should be converted to
" ab[c[kk] ]  ab[c[5] ]  sin(x) qr[g]  exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr[3] )) cos(y[3] )  sin(3)"  

As a first shot, I run the input thru this regex first  (R code) to find numeric indices,
str1 <- gsub('([^a-z][a-z]{1,2})[(]([0-9]{1,})[)]' ,'\\1\\[\\2\\] ' , thestr)

Next I look for indices which are names of variables
str2 <- gsub('([^a-z][a-z]{1,2})[(]([^)]{1,})[)]' ,'\\1\\[\\2\\] ' , str1)

Which succeeds only if I recurse on the second regex.    I'm hoping there's a cleaner approach, and preferably one that doesn't require repeating the operation.

mandatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/86072 . On a more serious note: "correctly parse parentheses (in all situations)" is a task that cannot be achieved with regular expressions alone. Look for a parser (a FOCAL parser apparently ?), or perhaps someone can point you to an alternative to pure regexps.

Here is an open source focal compiler which has a --no-run option to just act as a parser. I'm not exactly sure what the output with that option would be but I agree that trying to implement your own parser with regular expressions is not going to get you very far so, depending on the complexity of your task, that might be a good place to start.

@SamR  thanks -- in this case I'm doing all this purely for my own enjoyment, so using someone else's compiler would be a downer :-)

The first two altenatives below split the input into substrings that are valid R code and then use R's tokenzier or internal expression tree.  The third and fourth deal directly with strings using a regex or gsubfn.  (3) is likely the fastest.
1) getParseData Not clear what the general case may be but if we fix the unbalanced parentheses in cos(y(3))) then this works with the input shown.  It breaks the input at whitespace and then applies fix_parens to each component.  It tokenizes the input using getParseData and then keeping track of the parenthesis type in parens it replaces the ones following a one or two character name and its match.  The utils package comes with R so it does not need to be installed.
library(utils)

fix_parens <- function(x) {
  txt <- getParseData(parse(text = x))$text
  txt <- txt[txt != ""]
  out <- txt
  paren <- c()
  for(i in seq_along(txt)[-1]) {
    if (nchar(txt[i-1]) %in% 1:2 && txt[i] == "(") {
      paren <- c(paren, "]")
      out[i] <- "["
    } else if (txt[i] == "(") {
      paren <- c(paren, ")")
    } else if (txt[i] == ")") {
      out[i] <- tail(paren, 1)
      paren <- head(paren, -1)
    }
  }
  paste0(out, collapse = "")
}
# same as revised version in question
inp <- " ab(c(kk)) ab(c(5)) sin(x) qr(g) exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr(3))) cos(y(3))  sin(3)"

s <- strsplit(inp, " +")[[1]]
s <- s[s != ""]
paste(unname(sapply(s, fix_parens)), collapse = " ")
## [1] "ab[c[kk]] ab[c[5]] sin(x) qr[g] exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr[3])) cos(y[3]) sin(3)"

2) R expressions Another approach is to use R expressions with a recursive function.  s is from (1),
fix_parens2 <- function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) x <- parse(text = x)[[1]]
  if (is.symbol(x) || is.numeric(x)) return(x)
  n <- nchar(as.character(x[[1]]))
  if (n %in% 1:2) {
    as.call(c(as.name("["), x[[1]], fix_parens2(x[[2]])))
  } else as.call(c(x[[1]], lapply(x[-1], fix_parens2)))
}

paste(unname(sapply(s, fix_parens2)), collapse = " ")
## [1] "ab[c[kk]] ab[c[5]] sin(x) qr[g] exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr[3])) cos(y[3]) sin(3)"

3) regex  This uses a recursive regex to match a 1 or 2 word name, a parenthesis and the content and matching parenthesis replacing the outermost instance repeating as needed.
fix_parens3 <- function(x) {
  pat <- "(\\b\\w{1,2})\\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))*)\\)"
  prev <- x
  repeat {
    x <- gsub(pat, "\\1[\\2]", x, perl = TRUE)
    if (x == prev) break
    prev <- x
  }
  x
}

fix_parens3(inp)
## [1] " ab[c[kk]] ab[c[5]] sin(x) qr[g] exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr[3])) cos(y[3])  sin(3)"

4) gsubfn gsubfn is like gsub except the replacement string can be a replacement proto object which inputs the match to method fun and replaces the match with the output from fun.  pre is run at the beginning of the string to initialize any variables used by fun that are used across invocations of fun.  The logic follows (1) farily closely but has no explicit loop.
library(gsubfn)

p <- proto(pre = function(this) this$paren <- c(),
fun = function(this, x) {
  if (nchar(x) %in% 2:3) {
    this$paren <- c(this$paren, "]")
    sub("(", "[", x, fixed = TRUE)
  } else if (nchar(x) > 3) {
    this$paren <- c(this$paren, ")")
    x
  } else {
     ret <- tail(this$paren, 1)
     this$paren <- head(this$paren, -1)
     ret
  }
})

gsubfn("(\\w+\\(|\\))", p, inp)
## [1] " ab[c[kk]] ab[c[5]] sin(x) qr[g] exp(cos(qr)) exp(z) exp(cos(qr[3])) cos(y[3])  sin(3)"


These look good.   I fixed that extraneous parenthesis (mentioning that so future readers aren't confused)

Have added alternatives (3) and (4).

Wow.  Guess I really stimulated your inquisitiveness neurons!  :-)
